# How to convert Dataframe into Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to convert N columns into one series. How to do it effectively?

Input:

```
    0   1   2   3
0  64  98  47  58
1  80  94  81  46
2  18  43  79  84
3  57  35  81  31
```

Expected Output:

```
0     64
1     80
2     18
3     57
4     98
5     94
6     43
7     35
8     47
9     81
10    79
11    81
12    58
13    46
14    84
15    31
dtype: int64
```

So Far I tried:

```
print df[0].append(df[1]).append(df[2]).append(df[3]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I'm not satisfied with my solution, moreover it won't work for dynamic columns. Please help me to find a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Series` class and `.values` attribute:

```
pd.Series(df.values.T.flatten())
```

Output:

```
0     64
1     80
2     18
3     57
4     98
5     94
6     43
7     35
8     47
9     81
10    79
11    81
12    58
13    46
14    84
15    31
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
pd.Series(df.unstack().values)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need [np.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)

```
pd.Series(df.values.flatten(order='F'))

out[]
0     64
1     80
2     18
3     57
4     98
5     94
6     43
7     35
8     47
9     81
10    79
11    81
12    58
13    46
14    84
15    31
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another short one.

```
>>> pd.Series(df.values.ravel(order='F'))                                                                                                               
>>> 
0     64
1     80
2     18
3     57
4     98
5     94
6     43
7     35
8     47
9     81
10    79
11    81
12    58
13    46
14    84
15    31
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.melt.html) -

```
df.melt()['value']
```

**Output**

```
0     64
1     80
2     18
3     57
4     98
5     94
6     43
7     35
8     47
9     81
10    79
11    81
12    58
13    46
14    84
15    31
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.T.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Out:

```
0     64
1     80
2     18
3     57
4     98
5     94
6     43
7     35
8     47
9     81
10    79
11    81
12    58
13    46
14    84
15    31
dtype: int64
```